# Allow user to manage EC2 by its tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, architecture, amazon-iam

I am trying to enable access to EC2 for our vendor . So, what I did : I add tag "Vendor" for dedicated  EC2 instances .

[image]

Then ,  I add policy below ..

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "ec2:*",
            "Resource": "*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "ec2:ResourceTag/Vendor": "Takamol"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateTags",
                "ec2:DeleteTags",
                "ec2:TerminateInstances"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Nevertheless , the user (who belongs to group that attaches)  cannot see any EC2 instance even the policy condition restricts by tag "Vendor" (as you notice) .

How can allow user to manage only EC2 instances which has tag : Vendor = Takamol

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you're trying to achieve isn't possible. This is because of a concept called "Resource Level Permissions". Actions that support Resource level permissions allow you to use IAM to allow/deny a user the ability to perform an action on some subset of the resources in question, e.g. EC2 instances with a particular tag, S3 buckets, VPCs etc. Actions that don't support Resource Level Permissions can only be allowed/denied for ALL resources, and can only be allowed to a user in a statement where the resource is * and where there are no conditions.

Unfortunately for you, not all EC2 Actions support Resource Level Permissions. The reason that your user can't see any EC2 instances with the above IAM policy is that the ec2:Describe* API calls (used in the console to list all the instances in the account) do NOT support resource level permissions.

So even though ec2:Describe* falls under ec2:* which you allow for tagged instances in the first statement in the policy, ec2:Describe* with a condition evaluates to DENY all ec2:Describe*.

What people usually end up doing is allowing the vendor access to see all instances in the account and then only allow them the additional permissions they need for a particular set of instances. See the policy below, it will allow the user to see all instances but only start, stop and reboot instances with the required tag.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AllowSeeEverything",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:Describe*"
        ],
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "ThingsIAllowThemToDoForTaggedEc2s",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:RebootInstances",
            "ec2:StartInstances",
            "ec2:StopInstances"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:ResourceTag/Vendor": "Takamol"
            }
        },
        "Resource": [
            "*"
        ]
    }
]
```

}

The list of what EC2 API calls support resource level permissions along with what conditions are supported is documented in [Supported Resource-Level Permissions for Amazon EC2 API Actions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-supported-iam-actions-resources.html). I also recommend reading the [Demystifying EC2 Resource-Level Permissions](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/demystifying-ec2-resource-level-permissions/)
 blog post.